# Java generics casting to <?>

Tags: java, generics, casting

I have the following class

```
public class DBField<T>
{
  protected String fieldName;
  protected FieldConverter c;
  protected T value;
  protected DataObject dataObject;

  public T getValue()
  {
    return value;
  }

  public void setValue(T value)
  {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public DBField(DataObject dataObject, String fieldName, FieldConverter c)
  {
    this.fieldName = fieldName;
    this.c = c;
    this.dataObject = dataObject;
  }
}
```

T is supposed to be Boolean, Float, String etc.

```
protected void ValuesToFields(List<Object> values, List<DBField<?>> fields) throws Exception
  {
    if (values.size() != fields.size())
      throw new Exception("Length does not match.");
    for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++)
    {
      Class valueClass = values.get(i).getClass();
      Class fieldClass = fields.get(i).getValue().getClass();
      if (valueClass.equals(fieldClass))
      {
        fields.get(i).setValue(values.get(i));
      }
      else
        throw new Exception("type mismatch");
    }
  }
```

Object is also supposed to contain Boolean, Float, String etc.

The problem with this code is

```
fields.get(i).setValue(values.get(i));
```

The syntax checker tells me I need to cast values.get(i) (to ? i suspect). How do I do this? I already tried valueClass.cast(values.get(i)) but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your code to be safe, for each `i`, the i'th element of `values` must be an instance of the type parameter of the `DBField` that is the i'th element of `fields`. Your code does not guarantee that this holds, and in fact there is no way to declare them in Java to ensure that this relationship between corresponding elements is true. And due to type erasure, you can't even check at runtime that the elements are right, because given a field, you don't know its type parameter. So there must be some unchecked casts, and we must take on faith that the arguments are correct.

The simplest thing to do would be to cast each field to `DBField<Object>`:

```
((DBField<Object>)fields.get(i)).setValue(values.get(i));
```

This is kind of saying "trust us, we know that this field can take any `Object`", and thus it can take a value of any type. It is kind of lying, because we know there are supposed to be fields whose type parameter is not `Object`, but since we must make some kind of unchecked cast anyway, this "unsafe cast" is no worse than the other solutions.

Alternately, if you don't want to do this arguably dubious cast, a more "legitimate" way would be to write a private helper method -- a "wrapper helper" -- which explicitly names the type parameter of the field, allowing us to simply cast to the value to this type:

```
private <T> static void ValueToField(Object value, DBField<T> field) {
    field.setValue((T)value);
}

//...
ValueToField(values.get(i), fields.get(i));
```

Note that the cast here is also an unchecked cast. The disadvantage of this method is that it requires the overhead of writing an extra method.

P.S. Your checks with `valueClass` and `fieldClass` are not very good. First of all, if the value of a field is currently `null`, it will cause a null pointer exception. Also, the value of a `DBField<T>` is any instance of `T`, whose actual class may be a subclass of `T`; so if you use this to check, it might lead to bad results. It's probably best if `DBField` contains the class object of the class of `T`, so it can be used to check. Also, you shouldn't compare equality with the value's actual class, since a subclass of `T` would also work, so you should check `fieldClass.isInstance(values.get(i))` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`if(values.get(i) instanceof valueClass)` ?

Comment: How would this help? Just putting an if before the line does not solve the line with the error that is left untouched this way. The problem is that setValue expects Boolean, String etc while values.get(i) is an object.

Comment: I meant replacing your `if` with mine. I figured it might be an issue with the Syntax checker that checking 2 classes equal each other wasn't good enough.

Answer (score -1):

You have a `List<Object>`.

You should have a `List<DBField<Object>>` to match it, or change your first list to `List<?>`

Comment: This does not help. The problem is that setValue expects Boolean, String etc while values.get(i) is an object.

Comment: i'd say change your list<object> parameter to list<?>, which basically means the same thing, and the syntax warning should go away